# How do I know which library files I have to set up in my linker menu in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, glut, glew

My task is to run a project from github in Visual Studio.

If I try to build the code I get 1626 errors, all of them LNK errors like:

> LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QString::~QString(void)" (_*imp*??1QString@@QEAA@XZ)

I think that it has something to do with the additional dependencies in the linker menu.

But I don't really know which libraries files I have to link there.

How do I know which library files I have to set up in my linker menu?
The Readme file on Github is not really helpful.

I have tried to link ANN, GLUT and GLEW (because the Readme from Github) but I don't know if it is correct.

I have tried to link Qt 4 because of the code I think it is also necessary for me.

Comment: ¿Doesn't the project on github have any project or make files bundled?

Comment: `QString` is part of QT so you will need ro link with the QT libraries.

Comment: How are you running moc, uic, rcc? You can't just add `Additional Dependencies` for a Qt project and expect it to work.

Comment: ***The Readme file on Github is not really helpful.*** Does the github site have a .pro or a CMakeLists.txt? These are 2 common options for using a Qt based project with many different IDEs. I use CMake with My Qt development on Visual Studio since 2008 at work.

Comment: Yes it has a CMakeLists.txt. Here is the Link by the way to the project: https://github.com/HongqiangWei/L1-Skeleton

Comment: You may want to use Docker and this fork: [https://github.com/jasonkena/L1-Skeleton](https://github.com/jasonkena/L1-Skeleton)

Comment: I looked at the repository. This project will be very difficult for you to use because it uses and requires 7+ year old dependencies. Even with Visual Studio's CMake support and Microsoft's vcpkg for dependencies this is not a beginner task at all. You will need to be experienced with these tools to get this to work in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

the project in github should (!) provide a list of dependencies.
If not, the only solution is either to guess, which packages provides the missing stuff or **googling the missing function names** and puzzle the list of dep's yourself.

Comment: the dependencies list on github only says: +ANN (1.1.2); +VCG (1.0.0); +GLUT (3.6); +GLEW (2.0); +Too can use: +MSVC >= 2010; +GCC >= 4.9.x. I have linked the lib file and the include file from ANN, GLUT and GLEW. And linked only the include file from VCG because VCG doesn't have an lib file.

Comment: So you think I don't have to link other liberaries file than in the dependencies list?

Comment: From the error message, it looks like the OP is not linking with Qt

Comment: did you google? e.g. "QString" directly sends you to QT ... this should deliver a large part of the missing things, then goto next function that the linker complains to still be missing ...

Comment: how do I link OP with Qt?

Comment: Um, *you're* the OP :)